# how to excludes and include task in ant script

Tags: ant

I want to copy only specific jar file using ant script. It is very easy task but i am not able to do this. I have written the below ant script for this task. I want to excludes all jar file except aopalliance-.jar file. But when i run this script it excludes all the jar file. can someone correct this script .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project default="mvcexample" name="MVCExample" basedir=".">
    <property name="web.dir" value="WebContent" />
    <property name="webinf.dir" value="WebContent/WEB-INF" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <property name="lib2.dir" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib2" />

    <target name="copyjar">
        <copy todir="${lib2.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" excludes="**/*.jar">
                <include name="${lib.dir}/aopalliance-.jar"></include>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
<target name="copyjar">
    <copy todir="${lib2.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <!-- <include name="${lib.dir}/aopalliance-.jar"/> -->             
            <include name="aopalliance-.jar"/> <!-- Don't put the dir name! -->            
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

When you specify a directory, you merely specify the name pattern under that directory. What you were asking for was the jar `${lib.dir}/${lib.dir}/aopalliance-.jar`. By the way, is there suppose to be a version number in there somewhere? Like `aopalliance-3.4.jar`? If so, you need `<include name="aopalliance-*.jar"/>`.

Also notice that if I used `<include .../>` instead of `<include...></include>`.